# How to display alert dialog in activity after user resume app

Tags: android, user-interface, android-alertdialog, session-timeout

ISSUE AT HAND:

The app itself will perform an auto session timeout logout when the app is pushed to the background or when the screen has time out. Hence, to facilitate better user interaction, I have included in an Alert Dialog to inform user that the account has been logout due to session timeout and require them to re-login again. The session Timeout method functions normally and properly.

However, I am not able to get the wanted result when I place the AlertDialog method in onResume(). Below is the snippet of the code that has been done. Could anyone please help so that the AlertDialog can be displayed when the user resumes the activity.

```
//EDITED FOR SESSION LOGOUT
//WHEN APP IS IN IDLE OR WHEN USER DEVICE SCREEN IS OFF, WILL CALL ON THE METHOD TO LOGOUT USER

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setloginButton();
    EnquiryActivity.PROPERTY = 0;
    //EDITED FOR SESSION LOGOUT
    //Get the Resume Time
    resumeDate = new Date();
    long diff = resumeDate.getTime() - curDate.getTime();
    long secInt = diff / 1000 % 60; //conversion of milliseconds into human readable form
    if (secInt > Inactivity_Timeout){// SET EXIT SCREEN INTERVAL LOGOUT
        IdleLogout();
        AlertDialog();
    }   
}

@Override
public void onUserInteraction() { 
    super.onUserInteraction();
    // TO LOG APP HAS EXITED AND IS PUSHED TO BACKGROUND PROCESS(25/08/2014) 
    .....
}

//Perform Check if User is still Login as an user
public void checkLogin(){
    //CONDITION TO CHECK IF USER IS LOGIN, IF TRUE, CALL METHOD 
 ....
}


 public void startUserInactivityDetectThread(){ 
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // PROVIDING AN INFINITE LOOP WHEN FOLLOWING CONDITIONS ARE TRUE. 
         while(true) {
                  //Perform Thread to check on condition and run idlelogout
        }
       }
       }).start();
       }

public void IdleLogout(){
 // Method to perform logout and erase shared preference credential
}

// TO INFORM USER ON THE STATUS OF LOGOUT WHEN USER RESUMES THE APP
public void AlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RootActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("SESSION LOGOUT NOTICE");
    alertDialog.setMessage("PLEASE LOGIN TO ACCESS YOUR PROFILE.");
    //SETTING OF OK BUTTON
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.og.ascendas.spacetobe"));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
    });alertDialog.show();// SHOW ALERT MESSAGE
}
```

Comment: y do you name your method the same as the class(AlertDialog)??

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal it wasn't logged in Logcat when I run it!! I can't actually place the alertdialog method outside of the loop condition cause, this will cause the function to fail, in the sense that the user will not be able to log in and the alertdialog message keeps showing

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal, nope.not at all. still trying

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal yes, the idlelogout methods works inside the if (secInt > Inactivity_Timeout){} loop

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal so may I know what are you hinting at?? I am still not getting it.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal I am sorry, I don't get your meaning?? How do you tell if JVM execution control is functioning inside the if(){} loop

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal, the execution flow in the if(){...} loop is functioning when the if condition is satisfied. That's why IdleLogout happens and alertdialog is not called. I can't place alertdialog outside the "if" condition as it will not function properly.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal code has been edited.

Comment: I implement the alertdialog method after IdleLogout and I input the alert dialog method into the if condition in OnResume(). I have tried calling alertdialog() method in IdleLogut() but the dialog didn't show

Comment: you are doing `startActivity(getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class));` may be this is the reason..

Comment: this is the page that I want user to be in when the app is restarted from idle. May I know why you would think that could be the issue?

Comment: `AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RootActivity.this).create();` and `startActivity(getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class));` thats why you get error on `create()`

Comment: okkayy!!then may i ask what is your proposed solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this homes, i assuming your implemtation is good. so addressing your problem solely on your problem..lol
implement it using this way so urs gonna be like this(Edditing starts from here)

```
static Builder alertDialog(Activity act,final Intent yourintent){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    alertDialog.setTitle("SESSION LOGOUT NOTICE");
    alertDialog.setMessage("PLEASE LOGIN TO ACCESS YOUR PROFILE.");
    //SETTING OF OK BUTTON
    alertDialog.setPossitiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.og.ascendas.spacetobe"));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        act.startActivity(yourintent);//Return page to PROPERTYACTIVITY
      }
   });      
return alertDialog;
}
```

i placed the startActivity in the alertdialog, so when the user clicks ok-in respect to logging in then it will take him to the login screen, like you want it, then let onresume do its show();

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    setloginButton();
    EnquiryActivity.PROPERTY = 0;
    //EDITED FOR SESSION LOGOUT
    //Get the Resume Time
    resumeDate = new Date();
    long diff = resumeDate.getTime() - curDate.getTime();
    long secInt = diff / 1000 % 60; //conversion of milliseconds into human readable form
    if (secInt > Inactivity_Timeout){// SET EXIT SCREEN INTERVAL LOGOUT
         IdleLogout();
         RootActivity.alertDialog(RootActitvity.this,getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class)).create().show();
        }
}
```

or put it in IdleLogout()

```
public void IdleLogout(){
   // Method to perform logout and erase shared preference credentials
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE);             
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();       
   editor.clear();     // CLEAR ALL FILEDS
   editor.commit();    // COMMIT CHANGES 
   setloginButton();   // Change logout button to login       
   RootActivity.alertDialog(RootActitvity.this,getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class)).create().show();
}
```

sorry for the little errors i wrote offhead from a drowsy state..correct little errors
if you put it in idlelogout() dont call it in onresume direct, just call your idlelogout and also this is not relevant

```
editor.remove(getString(R.string.pref_username));   //REMOVE USERNAME FROM STRING
editor.remove(getString(R.string.pref_password));  //REMOVE PASSWROD FROM STRING
```

because clear() does that.. and also note to remove startActivity(getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class)); //Return page to PROPERTYACTIVITY. from your idlelogout..ok..
let me know if its good

Comment: alright, will try and let you know!!Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: would just like to confirm. I will have to change the name of the second alertDialog() method to something else right? else, it wouldn't actually be correct. Secondly, at alertDialog.create();, it states that a cast needs to be added?? Thirdly,  alertDialog().show();, it states that it cannot be resolved or not a field and this method should be placed inside if (secInt > Inactivity_Timeout){ condition, yes?

Comment: Yes-the first example, was the general sample of what i did in the second example so copy paste the second example to replace your public void AlertDialog(){} method get it.. and show it in your onresume.. and i didnt get what you meant in your second quest. and to your third quest put the builder method in the same class as your onresume..@ErnestLee

Comment: to be safer put the alertdialog in IdleLogout(){} method so when logout is done then login dialog pops up..but i tot your implemetation was working jux the alertdialog..

Comment: the entire session logout method is working, is the alert dialog that i am an issue.

Comment: and i have put the alertdialog into the IdleLogout{} method before, but it didnt call as well

Comment: I have done what you have suggested, that is to insert the alertdialog into the Idlelogout() method, however, I am getting an error for this line: [alertDialog.create();] the error states that this method is undefined for the alerdialog() method. The implementation works fine for the other codings

Comment: im sorry this was entirely my fault i made an error..please check my editted version..sorry sorry..

Comment: mostly what you have to do is check if user is offline-(time is due like you are doing) then when the alertdialog popos up, and user clicks ok, then call the intent to fire the logging in activity does all the login you need to programm around.. check my edit @ErnestLee

Comment: Thanks, will try!! However, I would like to ask, in regards to the "Static" identifier to Builder AlertDialog() method. I understand that to input static is to allow the function to operate once as long as the process is alive. However, in static function, it doesn't allow the input of RootActivity.this and the startActivity(getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class));.  Sorry, that I am asking so much, I am trying to learn. Thanks for your help by the way!!appreciate it!

Comment: yes sorry you are right, i just wrote it offhead, so correct little eerrors, but i just corrected alot of them..hope it helps you..if not, thats some hella problem you got..@ErnestLee

Comment: im glad it helped you..happy codding & be great..@ErnestLee